# Can I use "if not exists" to insert a row if the row is not already present in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
insert into Attributes (Id, Disabled, AttributeValue) 
values (@id, @disabled, @attr_value)
if not exists
(
select * from Attributes
where 
Id = @id
)
```

- Not sure, if this is a valid query.
- I have seen people use where not exists. What is the difference and how to use where not exists? When I put *where not exists*, it is saying "Incorrect syntax near where."

I checked these question as well. But, it doesn't seem to have query to insert using *if not exists*. 
[Only inserting a row if it's not already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there) and 
[sql conditional insert if row doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290792/sql-conditional-insert-if-row-doesnt-already-exist)

- Am I missing something? Should I only use *where not exists*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to execute something like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Attributes where Id = @id)
BEGIN
    insert into Attributes (Id, Disabled, AttributeValue) 
    values (@id, @disabled, @attr_value)
END
```

This is typically done with an else clause to update the row if it exists.

Comment: I think you could have a race condition with this - where an Attribute with the given ID is inserted after the test by something else, but you still insert.  Bluefeet's answer is better because it's executed as a single query and so avoids the possibility of a race condition.

Answer (score 11):

Change it to `INSERT INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO Attributes (Id, Disabled, AttributeValue) 
SELECT @id, @disabled, @attr_value
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    select * from Attributes
    where 
    Id = @id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
MERGE INTO Attributes 
   USING ( values (@id, @disabled, @attr_value ) ) 
            AS source ( Id, Disabled, AttributeValue )
      ON source.Id = Attributes.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ( Id, Disabled, AttributeValue )
      VALUES ( Id, Disabled, AttributeValue );
```

One advantage is that you can also update the values when the `Id` does exist e.g.

```
MERGE INTO Attributes 
   USING ( values (@id, @disabled, @attr_value ) ) 
            AS source ( Id, Disabled, AttributeValue )
      ON source.Id = Attributes.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET Id = source.Id,
          Disabled = source.Disabled, 
          AttributeValue = source.AttributeValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ( Id, Disabled, AttributeValue )
      VALUES ( Id, Disabled, AttributeValue );
```

Comment: What if I don't want to update, but just insert? Would MERGE perform better than the two queries mentioned above? or you think it would be easier to modify if one day I chose to update apart from insert?

Comment: Even for `INSERT` actions alone I think there is a good chance `MERGE` will perform better. I suggest you test it using typical data. Speaking of future proofing, consider that `MERGE` is standard SQL and widely supported (Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc) and therefoer higly portable when the time comes to move your successful application to a new platform :)